# Checked property coming incorrectly in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm setting a checked property for checkbox using JQuery as `$('#food').prop('checked' , true);

The checked property is setting in HTML code but not correctly. The property is being set as `checked"= " ".` Why is it happening so? What could be the issue.

**HTML code:**

```
<input type="radio" name="food" value="yes" id="food">
```

Comment: Can you add you html code here?

Comment: Please share your html code

Comment: Edited the question. Included HTML code

Comment: Typo mistake lets close it.

Answer (score 1):

Because `false` converted as blank in browser

```js
checked = false;
function toggleChecked(){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked' , checked);
  $('#test').html(checked);
  console.log("checked : "+checked);
  checked = !checked;
  
}
toggleChecked();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="button" onclick="toggleChecked()" value="Toggle">
<div id="test"></div>
```

Same for radio type

```js
checked = false;
function toggleChecked(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked' , checked);
  $('#test').html(checked);
  console.log("checked : "+checked);
  checked = !checked;
  
}
toggleChecked();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio">
<input type="button" onclick="toggleChecked()" value="Toggle">
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="food" value="yes" id="food" checked="">
```

You have an HTML error, that's what it should look like.

More precisely, this piece of code - jQuery code is correct

```
checked"=""
```

Look: https://jsfiddle.net/dtdLnfhg/

Comment: Typo error is happening when I set the property in Jquery, Initially the property will no be there in the HTML. HTML code will be just <input type="radio" name="food" value="yes" id="food" >

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dtdLnfhg/1/ - this way? Change to true click run and see how it works

Answer (score 0):

As expected there's an error in your HTML code. There's an extra quote " after checked. Just remove it.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked' , true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="food" value="yes" id="food" checked="">
```